# Excluding words or phrase in solr search

Tags: solr

I have following solr field configured and wanted to see how can I eliminate some words from search. For e.g fries, fried etc.. I tried putting it in stopwords.txt, but doesn't works solr still returns results.
Another question I have is.

How can I limit search such that if text contains two words that are close or separate it should return matching results for e.g

If i search for shrimp poboy it should return 1 and 3 and not 2.

1. I like shrimp poboy
2. shrimp vegetable
3. shrimp sandwich under poboy sandwich category

   ```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <!--tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/-->
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(;|,|-)\s*" replacement=" " replace="all"/>   
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(\p{Punct}*)(.*?)(\p{Punct}*)$" replacement="$2"/>       
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
           generateWordParts="1"
           generateNumberParts="1"
           catenateWords="1"
           catenateNumbers="1"
           catenateAll="0"
           preserveOriginal="1"
           />
   <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.keyword.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <!--tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/-->
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(;|,|-)\s*" replacement=" " replace="all"/>                       
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(\p{Punct}*)(.*?)(\p{Punct}*)$" replacement="$2"/>                   
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
           generateWordParts="1"
           generateNumberParts="1"
           catenateWords="1"
           catenateNumbers="1"
           catenateAll="0"
           preserveOriginal="1"
           />      
   <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.keyword.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>     
           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
           <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
           <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
         </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
   ```

Comment: I tried the approach you suggested, so If i just search for fries, nothing is returned which is ok, but then if I search for 
fried rice, the fried is excluded but searches only for rice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the words you want to exclude from search, you need to add another filter in there:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
```

If it still doesn't work, go to the Solr admin panel, go to Analysis and try out a query with stopwords. See how it gets processed.

For the second one, Solr offers proximity search - just use a `~2` after the query to specify that the words need to be at most 2 words apart from each other.

Comment: Thanks Ansari. Will give it a try and let you know. Also, third question.

Can “&” and “and” work interchangebly like synonms when doing exact match “mac & cheese”